# Django basic ModelForm not showing choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Using [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), I built a basic ModelForm with choice fields:

1. One field (Shirt size) -  is not showing choices
2. Second field - not showing at all

I can't find the reason, anywhere I checked it seems like I'm doing things right, but obviously I'm not.

Thank you.

**The Result Form**
[image]

**views.py**

```
def person(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PersonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = forms.PersonForm()

    return render(request, 'development/form_template.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='Anonymous', help_text='Type your name.')
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
    medal_type = models.TextChoices('MedalType', 'GOLD SILVER BRONZE')
```

**form_template.html**

```
{% extends 'development/development_template.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
        <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**CSS files I'm using**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: `TextChoices` is not a model field so there will not be a field generated for it. As for `shirt_size` there seems to be some strange CSS on your page, the text input for `name` is not even rendering properly

Comment: I used `TextChoices` as suggested in the tutorial, what should I use instead?

Comment: Added the CSS I'm using - Materializedcss

Comment: `TextChoices` is for creating an enum that can be used as choices for another field. It is not a model field on its own. Where in the tutorial does it say to use it?

Comment: Is the second field a select? Needs to be initialized if so. Also, you are serving both the minified and non minified css. Just one is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was 100% the support of Materializecss design in `select` - for some reason it's not supporting `select` anymore.

I used `bootstrap4` to execute the `form` pages:
(1) install: `pip install django-bootstrap4`
(2) add to `INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'bootstrap4',]`
(3) edit your HTML form

**Here's html for example:**

```
{% extends 'adolim/adolim_template.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
<div class="container"  style="width:100%;" dir="rtl">
    <div class="col s3 right">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 right" dir="rtl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><br></div>
                <h4 class="right">{{ page_title }}</h4>
            <div class="row"><br></div>
            <form dir="rtl" action="{% url 'adolim:add_order' %}" method="post" >
                {% csrf_token %}

                        {% bootstrap_form form %}

                <div class="col center">
                    {% buttons %}
                        <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue darken-1" type="submit" name="action">{{ page_title }} למערכת
                          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                     {% endbuttons %}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```